# Как найти определенный символ в String в Swift

Tags: ios, строки, swift

У меня есть textField. я получаю текст который ввел пользователь и должен проверить есть ли в этом тексте определенный символ. как получить этот символ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У String есть метод contains(_:) (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893238-contains тут есть пример использования).
Вот мой пример:

```
import Foundation

let myString = "Hello World"
let mySymbol = "W"
if myString.contains(mySymbol) { // ВОТ ТУТ ПРОИСХОДИТ ПРОВЕРКА НАЛИЧИЯ СИМВОЛА В СТРОКЕ
    print("Символ", mySymbol," в строке присутствует")
} else {
    print("Символ", mySymbol," в строке отсутствует")
}
```

Вывод консоли:

Символ W  в строке присутствует

Если поменять переменную mySymbol например на s, то вывод консоли такой:

Символ s  в строке отсутствует